# Событие SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: winforms

Значит у меня такая проблема. На форме есть flowLayoutPanel, на нее добавляются два comboBox'а при открытии формы, а по нажатию на кнопку "Добавить" добавляются еще такая же группа комбоБоксов. Т.е. они появляются уже после запуска программы. При создании этих элементов в комбоБокс_1 тянутся данные из БД (марка машины) а в комбоБокс_2, в зависимости от содержания комбоБокс_1, из БД тянутся модели машин. Однако это срабатывает только при запуске, и если менять комбоБокс_1, то комбоБокс_2 не меняется. Я так понял нужно как-то работать с событием SelectedIndexChanged у комбоБокс_1. Только вот как это делать с таким образом созданными комбоБоксами? Подскажите.